# DecoderFailure in cardano-cli

Tags: blockchain, nft, cardano

I'm facing some issues with cardano-cli. I'm using the Daedalus socket and trying to query the testnet.

When running this command `cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063` it returns the following:

```
cardano-cli: DecoderFailure (LocalStateQuery HardForkBlock (': * ByronBlock (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyMAEra 'Allegra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyMAEra 'Mary StandardCrypto)) ('[] *))))) Query (HardForkBlock (': * ByronBlock (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyEra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyMAEra 'Allegra StandardCrypto)) (': * (ShelleyBlock (ShelleyMAEra 'Mary StandardCrypto)) ('[] *))))))) ServerAgency TokQuerying QueryHardFork GetCurrentEra) (DeserialiseFailure 3 "EraIndex: invalid index 4")
```

However when executing `cardano-cli get-tip --testnet-magic 1097911063` it works fine.

What could be causing this? Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: did you ever find out what was causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I ran into this issue too and I was able to solve the issue by upgrading the cardano-cli

confirmed that this version of the cli:

```
cardano-cli --version
cardano-cli 1.30.1 - linux-aarch64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 0fb43f4e3da8b225f4f86557aed90a183981a64f
```

works with this version of the node:

```
cardano-node --version
cardano-node 1.34.1 - linux-aarch64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 73f9a746362695dc2cb63ba757fbcabb81733d23
```